# Plotting a parametric system of two differential equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the system of parametric equations below. The initial value ranges, in order to find the critical point where N[s]=0 and D[s]=0.

What is the best way to do this?

How can i plot the γu[s]=f(R[s]).

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

This is the code i use

```
\[CapitalGamma] = 5/3;
c4 = 6;
smax = 50;
Rinit = 1.05;
\[Gamma]uinit = 0.80;

t = Flatten@Table[\[Gamma]uinit + i, {i, 0, 0.03, 0.01}];

Sol1 = Quiet[
Catch[NDSolveValue[{D1[s] == 
    2 (-1 + R[s]) R[
      s] (-(-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[Gamma]u[s] + 
       c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - \[CapitalGamma])/
        2) (-2 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[s]^(
        2 - \[CapitalGamma]) + 
       c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - \[CapitalGamma])/
        2) (-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[
         s]^-\[CapitalGamma]), 
   N1[s] == -(1 + \[Gamma]u[s]^2) (1 - \[CapitalGamma] + 
       c4 (-1 + R[s])^(1/2 - \[CapitalGamma]/2)
         R[s]^(-(3/2) (-1 + \[CapitalGamma])) (2 + 
          4 R[s] (-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) - 
          3 \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[s]^(
        1 - \[CapitalGamma])), 
   R'[s] == D1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
   Derivative[1][\[Gamma]u][s] == N1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
   R[0] == Rinit, \[Gamma]u[0] == #, 
   WhenEvent[N1[s]*D1[s] == 0, Throw[{N1[s], D1[s]}]; 
    "Stop Integration"]}, {R, \[Gamma]u}, {s, 0, smax}]], 
NSDolveValue::noout] & /@ t
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Sow` and `Reap`? Does this is what you want?

```
Γ = 5/3;
c4 = 6;
smax = 50;
Rinit = 1.05;
γuinit = 0.80;
t = Flatten@Table[γuinit + i, {i, 0, 0.03, 0.01}];
Sol1 = Reap[
     NDSolveValue[{D1[s] == 
        2 (-1 + R[s]) R[
          s] (-(-1 + Γ) γu[s] + 
           c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - Γ)/
               2) (-2 + Γ) Γ γu[
              s]^(2 - Γ) + 
           c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - Γ)/
               2) (-1 + Γ) Γ γu[
              s]^-Γ), 
       N1[s] == -(1 + γu[s]^2) (1 - Γ + 
           c4 (-1 + R[s])^(1/2 - Γ/2) R[
              s]^(-(3/2) (-1 + Γ)) (2 + 
              4 R[s] (-1 + Γ) - 
              3 Γ) Γ γu[
              s]^(1 - Γ)), 
       R'[s] == D1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
       Derivative[1][γu][s] == N1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
       R[0] == Rinit, γu[0] == #, 
       WhenEvent[N1[s]*D1[s] == 0, Sow[{N1[s], D1[s]}];
        "Stop Integration"]}, {R, γu}, {s, 0, smax}]] & /@ t
ParametricPlot[
 Through[#@s] & /@ Sol1[[All ;; All, 1]] // Evaluate, {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The plot is fine, although i would like the function to be able to define the exact point where the WhenEvent takes place and plot it until the event. In the original code i have posted, i can see the s where integration stops for each γu[0]. Is this possible with your answer?

Comment: `Sol1[[All ;; All, 2]]`

Comment: Thank you again, but this only shows the value of s only for  the first time it integrates. The rest are blank. Furthermore it uses the s above to stop the integration for the rest of the curves and it is not the correct one.